# Navigate from a slice of a pie chart to another pie chart

Tags: powerbi

I have a general pie chart showing the number of emails sent by application like below : 
[image]

I want when clicking on the CCube slice for example, I go to another pie chart where I find number of the emails for the application CCube with failed and sent status like below :

[image]

Comment: Try a drill down. Do you want another PieChart or in the same PieChart?

Comment: I want both alternatives :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've used for this sort of thing is to use the [drill-down donut chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380858) custom visual instead of the default pie chart visual. It's pretty nifty.